# Eclipse Mars: No entry for Maven under Window-> Preferences

Tags: eclipse, m2eclipse, eclipse-mars

I have Mars2 version of Eclipse in my system. I had installed m2Eclipse to integrate maven with Eclipse from here http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases, however, I do not find the option for maven in Eclipse, neither under preferences nor under perspectives. Is there some other version of m2Eclipse to be used with Mars2 or what else can be done to resolve this issue?
Currently, I have Apache Maven 3.3.9 installed in my system along with JRE 1.7. I have other plugins as well like subclipse, beyond compare, JUNIT etc which seems to be installed properly.

Comment: File ->New ->other->type maven

Comment: Depending on the version of M2E, you might have to run Eclipse with the latest Java 8 (which is a good idea in general).

Comment: If my deployment environment has JAVA 1.7.0 instead, won't it create issues if I compile my project using Java 8?

Comment: Based on the posts available online, I should not be using Java 8 to build my projects when my deployment domain uses 1.7. Based on the information available here: https://eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/release-notes-17.html, version 1.7 of M2Eclipse targets Maven 3.3.9, which is what I have and it is compatible with Eclipse Mars as well

Comment: Open Help > About Eclipse and look for the M2 icon. Is it present?

Comment: The issue is resolved as mentioned in the answer below. the m2Eclipse compatible with Mars2 is 1.6, that targets maven 3.3.3. However, by default it is integrated in Mars 2. I was installing the latest version of m2Eclipse 1.7 on top of that which cause all these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

Right click on your `Project` --> Select `Configure` --> `Convert to Maven Project`

Comment: There is no option for Maven even though m2Eclipse is installed. This is the issue.

Comment: Which version of m2E you're using?

Comment: Currently installed version of m2e is 1.7, Eclipse Mars 2, Java 1.7 and apache maven 3.3.9

Comment: have you tried reinstalling eclipse? Who knows if its just a bug!

Comment: Currently, I am trying to install m2e version 1.6 which is fully compatible with Mars 2. I'll also change the maven version from 3.3.9 to 3.3.3 as mentioned here https://eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/release-notes-16.html. I am not sure if it would work, but worth a try

Comment: ya that was the thing in my mind & thats why I asked you about the version. also please check if project property-> build path -> lib tab shows maven dependency along with default JRE in the library path.

Answer (score 0):

m2eclipse is not required to be installed separately with Mars2. It is by default integrated with it when we download Mars2 binaries. Also, we should be targeting maven 3.3.3, since m2eclipse is version 1.6 which targets maven 3.3.3.

M2eclipse v1.7 targets maven 3.3.9 and is mainly targeted for Eclipse Neon